# Swift: access.propertry vs access.method()

Tags: swift, methods, syntax, properties

Is the title's example the only difference between accessing a property and calling a method?

It seems like properties are the things without a bracket, and methods calls always have a bracket for parameters to be passed to the method, even if there's no parameters to be passed.

Is that it for the major differences?

Coming from Objective-C, this seems like it's not enough different.

Comment: Did you read https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html? There are stored properties, computed properties, lazy properties, read-only properties, property observers, ....  So the syntax is not the major difference between properties and methods.

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between properties and methods, I'm asking about the difference in syntax between accessing them vs calling methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are the most clear difference... at least as far as access syntax is concerned. There are more differences in concept and implementation, as MartinR has alluded to in comments. (I'd encourage you to look at [that documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) he linked to see all the things that a property can encompass.)

One thing to note access-wise: property syntax encompasses both setter and getter "methods", sometimes both at once. So, with a method, if you want to retrieve, modify, and set a value, you have to call the getter, modify, then call the setter:

```
var bar: Int = foo.getBar()
bar += 1
foo.setBar(bar)
```

With properties, you can get and set in one operation:

```
foo.bar += 1

func increment(inout num: Int) { num++ }
increment(&foo.bar)
```

Behind the scenes, this calls the `get` accessor, modifies the value, and calls the `set` accessor — and calls `willSet`/`didSet` observers, too — regardless of whether you're dealing with a stored or computed property.

Comment: So, going in reverse, if a method call needs no passed parameter, is it possible to not bother with the ()?

Comment: No, because a method call always uses parentheses. `someObject.someMethod` gives you a reference to that method — you can pass that reference to anything that takes a closure. `someObject.someMethod()` actually calls (executes) the method.

Comment: If you're calling methods on some existing class, always use the parentheses (unless you want the closure). If you're writing your own class and implementing methods that take no parameters, consider whether it makes more sense to expose those as read-only properties.